# Apply filter using ng-repeat results

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem filtering results depending on ID of previous get request:

```
$http.get('https://www.immobiliaremartina.it/inc/show_all.php')
    .success(function (data) {$scope.results = data;})
    .error(function () {alert("Errore di connessione!")})

$http.get('https://www.immobiliaremartina.it/inc/showFoto.php')
    .success(function (data) {$scope.fotos = data;})
    .error(function () {alert("Errore di connessione!")})
```

After this two calls I want to show all pics in `fotos` depending on the ID of `results`

```
<div class="slider gal" >
    <ul class="slides" >
        <li ng-repeat="foto in fotos | filter: result.ID === foto.ID">
            <img src="/public/galleria/{{foto.URL}}">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

how is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

**js**

```
$scope.data = [];

var fotos = $http.get('https://www.immobiliaremartina.it/inc/showFoto.php')
var results = $http.get('https://www.immobiliaremartina.it/inc/show_all.php')

$q.all([fotos, results]).then(data => {
    var fotoResult = data[0];
    var resultResult = data[1];

    for(i= 0; i< fotoResult.length;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < resultResult.length;j++){
            if(fotoResult[i].ID === resultResult[j].ID){
                $scope.data.push(fotoResult[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="slider gal" >
    <ul class="slides" >
        <li ng-repeat="foto in data> 
            <img src="/public/galleria/{{foto.URL}}">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the above code waits for the results of both of your http requests and when they are loaded it filters data in your controller and shows filtered data in your html.

Comment: @DigitalXP inject $q to your controller

Comment: @DigitalXP have you changed your html?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
$scope.isInResults = function(foto){
  return results.filter((result) => result.id === foto.id)
};
```

and then

```
<li ng-repeat="foto in fotos | filter: isInResults">
    <img src="/public/galleria/{{foto.URL}}">
</li>
```